# UWP Hosted App - Link opens a new browser window despite content URI settings

Tags: windows, visual-studio, azure, uwp, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to package my PWA as a UWP using the Visual Studio template for a Hosted App that Microsoft has in Visual Studio. There is an azure login button on the login page that redirects people to Microsoft login page. I've specified all the redirect urls in the content URIs in visual studio, but the app still opens a new browser window (leaving the app, I need it to stay within the UWP window) every time I click the login button. Any ways around that?

[image: Redirects that the app uses]

[image: Content URIs settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is an azure login button on the login page that redirects people to Microsoft login page.

In general, you need to change your html code to achieve your target, but I did not see your original html source code of your web page, so I'm not sure.

If the 'login button' just is a simple `<a/>` tag like the following:

`<a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com" target="_blank">Login to Azure</a>`

Then if the `target` is set to '_blank', it will open a new windows in webbrowser when you click the link.

If the `target` is set to '_self', it will open the link document in UWP window.

Comment: Even with `target="_self"` it still opens a new window/tab in the default browser instead of loading the UWP app at that URL.